# Why there is difference between Islamic calender in the world?

Tags: sharia

Why Muslim in the world have to follow Islamic calender of there geographic location.

I mean can be a way that all Muslim could follow a same calender. I can understand when people have to see moon to knowing about current Islamic month cause there were no communication. The position of moon is different through geography so there is no same day through out world some people are living ahead and some people are living behind.

And It can also create blenders in history too.

Any detail about hadith  regarding or detail is what I am asking for.

Comment: I don't understand, I thought muslims have one Islamic calendar (Hijri calendar?)

Comment: The only time where muslims need to see the moon is for ramadan and eid al Fitr.

Comment: @Sohaeb yes muslim  only have Hijri calendar but the date of Hijri calendar varies around the world.

Comment: @Sohaeb we not just follow the moon for ramadan or eid al Fitr. every mouth of Islamic calendar has determine from moon. have you every think why ramadan have 29 or 30 days. it not only ramadan or zil hajj which is determine from moon but every other month too. but ramadan or zil hajj are important for us due to roza and eid.

Comment: @Hamza Review edit i will upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hijri Calender is based on the moon cycle so the moon will be seen on the different time on different geographical location so you must has to follow the calender of your location.

Can we follow same time all over the world. can the 12 pm in India will be equal to 12 pm of America, Not na . Since time is calculated on sun you can't consider it as same on the same geo area.

And this is Not only in Islamic Calender the date difference is also in English calender.
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/

> Allah's Messenger (peace_be_upon_him) said: Whenever you sight the new moon (of the month of Ramadan) observe fast, and when you sight it (the new moon of Shawwal) break it, and if the sky is cloudy for you, then observe fast for thirty days.
>   NARRATOR AbuHurayrah
>   SAHIH MUSLIM
>   HADITH_No 2378
>
> Allah's Messenger (peace_be_upon_him) said: Observe fast on sighting it (the new moon) and break it on sighting it. But if (due to clouds) the actual position of the month is concealed from you, you should then count thirty (days).
>   NARRATOR AbuHurayrah
>   SAHIH MUSLIM
>   HADITH_No 2380

Irrespective of geographical location.

Comment: your answer is correct.