# The Divine Night

Tags: laylat-al-qadr

Many people begin their month of Ramadan with Saudi Arabia despite living in other countries which normally are a day behind of Saudi Arabia according to lunar calendar.

In this case people would attend the odd night of last ten days according to Saudi Arabia and would miss the odd night of their country.

Are these people missing out on divine night too due to this practice or they are availing it solely due to their niyyat(intention)?

Comment: Imran, you asked a complicated question.
Definitely not, they do not miss the divine night.
So they get divine night, according to the total odd nights.
Because Allah do not create injustice for muslims.
All the muslims get their divine night according to the will of Allah.

Comment: @GhufranHasan, I am sorry but I am not satisfied with your answer unless you provide explanation to both sides of the question. Thank you for trying.

Comment: "Many people begin their month of Ramadan with Saudi Arabia despite living in other countries which normally are a day ahead of Saudi Arabia" - i think this is not true.

Comment: @qdinar, sorry, it is actually a day behind according to lunar calendar and I have edited this but I live in Pakistan and people do this practice this so it is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually they are missing the divine night of there country ... Every one has to follow the ruling of there countries... can you pray the Namaz at the same time as Saudi Arabia...

you can refer my this answer it suits this contex

[Why there is difference between Islamic calender in the world?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16408/why-there-is-difference-between-islamic-calender-in-the-world/16437#16437)

Comment: I agree with you and wanted to create awareness amongst those people who do this practice and miss out on the divine night.

Comment: yes every one must has to know this...

Comment: @Imran Do you think Divine night is concerned with a country? I think there is only one Divine night in the whole Ramdan for the whole world! And it may happen so that the Divine night come in even nights, because this is also possible...

Comment: @RehanUllah, If divine night comes in even night in one country then it is observed that people generally pray less in even nights than odd nights so those people who have divine night in even night may miss out on the divine night.

Comment: @Imran Yes Divine night is achieved by two things. First by Grace of Allah and second by our hard work. We should equally struggle in all the ten nights. Even  I had heard that there is possibility of Diving night in the whole ramadan from 11 to end so we should struggle whole ramadan.

Comment: @RehanUllah, I do not know and I will do more research on the topic before more discussion. Thank you for the input.

Comment: @RehanUllah, Just a recommendation which from now on I will imply on as well as that I will refrain answering unless having full knowledge otherwise I am doing a sinful act if I am telling something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Hadiths indicating that the Divine Night is mostly in Ramadan but maybe out of this month. And, Almighty ALLAH is the most Able. So, why are you all worried about this. The point is that how sincere your intention is.